# Prevent record from being inserted in before trigger without adding errors

Tags: trigger, dml, insert

Is it possible to prevent single record from being inserted in before trigger without `addError()`? I'd like to be able to insert just a subset of inserted records without throwing any errors.

Comment: what do you mean by subset here?

Comment: When someone tries to insert [a, b, c], I'd like to make it [a, b] in some conditions.

Comment: If you are doing bulk insert from apex then use `Database.insert` and it will only add error to specific record and will not stop other. Dataloader already provide this functionality.

Comment: @tusharSharma, please add it as an answer as it seems good enough for my requirements. Also, please mention the `all or none` flag in `database.insert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing bulk insert from apex then use `Database.insert` and it will only add error to specific record and will not stop other. Dataloader already provide this functionality.

Also don't forget to add `all or none` flag .